# How to enable a control if a CheckBox is Unchecked?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I know that is possible disable a `Control` if the `CheckBox` is not checked, generally I did this:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="myCheckBox" />
<Button IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=myCheckBox, Path=IsChecked}" />
```

this will enable the `Button` only if the `CheckBox` is checked, but there is a way in `Xaml` to enable the `Button` if the `CheckBox` is unchecked without create any `Converter?`

Pseudo code:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="myCheckBox" />
<Button IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=myCheckBox, Path=IsUnChecked}" />
```

Best regards.

Comment: If it's a frequent requirement then you could quite easily create a subclass of `CheckBox` with an additional property which is just a bitwise inversion of the `IsChecked` property, shove that in a dll full of your common functions and controls.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use the Binding with a DataTrigger:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="myCheckBox"/>
<Button x:Name="button">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=myCheckBox}"
                             Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Comment: I thought something like that, but I was looking for a shorter solution, I find absurd that for a simple operation like this we need all this code in wpf. However, thank you for your help, I appreciate it very much.

Comment: You won't get it shorter without a binding converter.

Answer (score -1):

Putting this answer to update visitors about the new syntax of `DataTrigger` to achieve the same. It worked for me on "Visual Studio 2015" or later.

```
        <CheckBox x:Name="myCheckBox"/>
        <Button x:Name="button">
            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Button">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=myCheckBox, Path=IsChecked}"
                                     Value="True">
                            <DataTrigger.Setters>
    <!--it would make the Button in Disabled state since checkbox is in Checked state-->
                              <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/> 
                        </DataTrigger.Setters>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=myCheckBox, Path=IsChecked}"
                                 Value="False">
                        <DataTrigger.Setters>
<!--it would make the Button in Enabled state since checkbox is in Unchecked state-->
                              <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                        </DataTrigger.Setters>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
```

I hope it helps all. Thanks!

Comment: This is in no way "new syntax". The explicit `<DataTrigger.Setters>` declaration has always been optional, because of `[System.Windows.Markup.ContentProperty("Setters")]` on the DataTrigger class. The second DataTrigger is also redundant.